# Google maps api v3 change icons/colors on mapstyleid change

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to change icons/colors on polylines etc. when you swtich from one custom map to another (via a simple mapstyleid change)?

Example:
When on maptypeid "Map1", a polyline would appear with a blue color. When switching to maptypeid "Map2", the same polyline would appear in yellow instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to code it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First you need to add an event to change of maptypeid then you need to use setOptions for polyline. Here is the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", function() {
  if(map.getMapTypeId()=="Map1"){
   yourPolyline.setOptions({strokeColor: '#ffffff'});
  }
});
```

you can find more properties here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions

Regards, 
Suyash